# HTML tags encoded when appending CDATA tag

Tags: jquery, encoding, html-parsing, cdata, html-encode

In my page, there is a div in which I have to display html from javascript. So in javascript, I append the CDATA tags so that the html is displayed as data. Following is the code I have used

```
var htmlCode = '<h>testing html</h>';
htmlCode = '<![CDATA[' + htmlCode+ ']]>';
$('myDiv').html(htmlCode);
```

This actually displays `testing html]]>` as the last `>` is converted into `&gt;` when I assign it to the html of the div. Any idea how to overcome this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, now what is the question? *last '>' is converted into > when*... So?

Comment: @SathyeshSelvarajah: The question wasn't formatted properly.

Comment: People just post the question, without even checking how it renders. Anyways, thanks for the edit @RocketHazmat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CDATA` is used in XML files.  it means the content inside is treated as text.  jQuery's `.html()` turns `<![CDATA[<h` into `<!--[CDATA[<h-->`, which is a comment.  It then ignores the closing `</h>` tag as the opening one is missing.  So, it displays `testing html]]>`.

If you want to display HTML as text, just use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.  It will escape it for you, so that it won't be parsed by the browser.

```
var htmlCode = '<h>testing html</h>';
$('#myDiv').text(htmlCode);
```

**EDIT**: You said you wanted the HTML *to* be parsed, then just use`.html`.

```
var htmlCode = '<h>testing html</h>';
$('#myDiv').text(htmlCode);
```

The `CDATA` is *not* needed in either case.

Comment: In the div I want to show the html and not text of the html. It should show "testing html" and not "<h>testing html</h>

Comment: @Ankit: Then just do `.html(htmlCode)`.  You don't need the `CDATA`, not sure why you had that.

Comment: @Hazmat: the htmlCode might not be well formatted html so I need to put it as CDATA

Comment: @Ankit: CDATA only works the (X)HTML file itself, not after the file has been parsed into the DOM.

Comment: @Hazmat: CDATA is used as the html might not be well parsed. The user enters an html in a textbox and on click of a button, I have to display it as html in a div.

Comment: @Ankit: Like I said, CDATA is only used in the *actual* (X)HTML file.  Once it's parsed by the browser, CDATA is not needed.  Either use `.html` or `.text` as shown.